# How to fix Android linking failed issue in Android Studio?

Tags: android

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.servercheck"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versioncode="1"
    android:versionname="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:minsdkversion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name="lakj.comspace.simpleclient.SimpleClientActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
                        </category>
                    </action>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </uses-sdk>

    <application
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true" />

</manifest>
```

Errors on bold words, how to solve the issue? I am making a client application In Android Studio. But these errors are occurring again and again?

Comment: Your screenshot shows manifest from build folder. Please add a screenshot by opening "AndroidManifest.xml" file left side-bar.

Comment: Added as an answer

Comment: @UmairNadeem Edit your question and add those screen shot in question as those images are not answer.

Comment: at the bottom right, swip to right unti you reach end and there you will find the error place.